# Find an exact match in an excell workbook then copy data from that row to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excell workbooks (wpt.xls & route.xls) that I'm using to make Waypoint & Route files. I would like to automate the process a bit by using a macro to find the row that contains "A-1" in column F in workbook (wpt.xls) then I would like to paste the data from column A into my other workbook (route.xls) into cell A1.  My sheet looks like the one below.

```
A   B       C       D               E          F
1   1   1   26-41.3143-N    082-52.0707-W   B-2
2   1   1   26-43.1669-N    082-47.6695-W   Z-3
3   1   1   26-49.7169-N    082-53.1127-W   Z-7
4   1   1   26-42.4121-N    082-51.9514-W   A-1
```

In this example I need "4" to be copied and pasted to my workbook (route.xls) into the the cell A1.

Comment: did you try to make some vb script or by any other language?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
=INDEX([wpt.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,MATCH(A1,[wpt.xlsx]Sheet1!$F$1:$F$4,0))
```

Enter that on the sheet in your route sheet, at the moment it looks in cell A1 for the item in col F you want.

[image]

Comment: The row changes all the time, so "A-1" may not be in the same cell.

Comment: Which row changes? Match looks in column F between cells F1 to F4 to find "a-1" at the moment. If the rows go down to F134, then edit the function to include those rows... If you mean on the "route" sheet that the target won't be in A1, then change A1 to b34 or whatever it is...