# Need to add values from multiple columns in one worksheet to another worksheet based on a match

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

One workbook, multiple worksheets (tabs)

Worksheet **1**.  There is data in each cell in Columns `A – K`.
For any given row, the values in Columns `G, H, I, J, K` directly correspond to the value in Column `B`

Worksheet **2**.  There is data in each cell in Columns `A – P`.

I would like a formula so that:
Whenever the value in Column `B` on Worksheet **1** matches any same value in Column `N` on Worksheet **2**, 
deliver the corresponding values from Columns `G, H, I, J, K` in Worksheet **1**     to Columns `Q, R, S, T, U` in Worksheet **2**.

Comment: Sounds like VLOOKUP to me.

Comment: Have a look at index() with match() see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726811/4961700  and example of vlookup : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747994/4961700

Comment: will definitely check out these references...I should clarify that the value in Column B in Worksheet 1 is always unique. There are 17,000+ rows of unique email addresses....not sure a simple vlookup is my answer, but I will check out the references you suggested

Comment: Is there way to post an example spreadsheet to show my problem?  I referenced the links above, unfortunately they do not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using INDEX and MATCH.

INDEX returns a value from an array, and we must provide a row and column. 
MATCH returns the location of a value in an array. If the array is a column, it will return the row number, if the array is a row, it will return a column number.
Say this is what your sheet1 looks like.:

[image: Sheet 1]

In this case, we want to find "happy" in column N of sheet 2, which may look like this:

[image: Sheet 2]

"happy" appears in column N on row 10. So, we want to retrieve "test" from G3 sheet 1 and want it to appear in Q10 Sheet 2. To do this, we can use the following code:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$K$10,MATCH(Sheet2!$N10,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10,0),7)
```

To break this down (focus on 1st and 3rd item [ignore the MATCH part for now]):

```
INDEX(array,row,col)
```

where array is sheet1 A1:P15. In column Q sheet 2, we want the value from Column G sheet 1, so the column number is 6 (6 = '7', which appears before the closing bracket).

But which row? Here's where MATCH comes into play:

```
MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])
```

We want the row where "happy" appears in column B sheet 1, and the MATCH formula we wrote is:

```
MATCH(Sheet2!$N10,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10,0)
```

Here, the value we want to look for is "happy" which is in N10, so that is our lookup_value (notice the `$N10`, column N is absolute, while row is relative).
Now where do we want to try finding "happy"? That's right, column B of Sheet 1, so we have `Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10` (we can also use `Sheet1!$B:$B` if we want to search the entire column). 
Lastly, we have match_type as 0, because 0 stands for exact value. We want to find the exact phrase "happy".

Putting it all together and we have the following code for column Q:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$K$10,MATCH(Sheet2!$N10,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10,0),7)
```

For column R, the only thing that changes is that we no longer want the value in column G sheet 1, we want the value from column H sheet 1, so the 7 at the end changes to an 8:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$K$10,MATCH(Sheet2!$N10,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10,0),8)
```

[image]

Sorry for the long explanation, just wanted to make sure you understood the code so you could edit it to suit your needs. Hope this helps.